# Qt5.4 How can I create an app based in plugins?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5.4

I have an app in QT 5.4 but when I need include a new functionality, I need recompile all the app, this take a time, I need know how create or modified my app to use plugins created by me.

Comment: Have you researched the topic?

Comment: You're most likely using a very slow compiler or a machine that's vastly underpowered for the job you're attempting.

Comment: How many lines of code are there in your project?

Comment: my solution is to use 8 threads to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plugin-based architecture requires binary compatible and stable interfaces. Once you have these, a full-project recompilation should take about as much time as recompiling a single plugin.

Most likely, you have interdependencies in your code that preclude maintaining binary compatibility anyway - if you didn't, your changes would be localized enough so that a recompilation would only touch a couple of files.

What you're trying to do is come up with a solution to the wrong problem. Fix the structure of your code, and your recompilation times will drop. No need for plugins.

Answer (score 0):

There are many alternatives; a popular one consists of using shared libraries implementing a well-defined API.

For example. Imagine this is the API you want to open for customization:

```
// pluggin_api.hpp
// This file defines the pluggin interface.
#pragma once

extern "C" { // avoid name mangling

const char* pluggin_name();
void foo(int x);
void bar(int y);

}
```

Then your users (or yourself) will implement different variations of this API, for example:

```
// pluggin_1.cpp

#include "pluggin_api.hpp"
#include <iostream>

const char* pluggin_name() {
  return "Pluggin 1";
}

void foo(int x) {
  std::cout << "2 * x = " << 2 * x << std::endl;
}

void bar(int y) {
  std::cout << " 3 * y = " << 3 * y << std::endl;
}
```

and

```
// pluggin_2.cpp

#include "pluggin_api.hpp"
#include <iostream>

const char* pluggin_name() {
  return "Pluggin 2";
}

void foo(int x) {
  std::cout << "20 * x = " << 20 * x << std::endl;
}

void bar(int y) {
  std::cout << " 30 * y = " << 30 * y << std::endl;
}
```

These .cpp files are compiled as shared libraries; under Linux it looks like this:

```
$ g++ -shared -fPIC -o pluggin_1.so pluggin_1.cpp
$ g++ -shared -fPIC -o pluggin_2.so pluggin_2.cpp
```

Finally, the main application can call the different pluggins by name:

```
// main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h> // POSIX --- will work on Linux and OS X, but
                   // you'll need an equivalent library for Windows

void execute_pluggin(const char* name) {
  // declare the signature of each function in the pluggin -- you
  // could do this in the header file instead (or another auxiliary
  // file)
  using pluggin_name_signature = const char*(*)();
  using foo_signature          = void(*)(int);
  using bar_signature          = void(*)(int);

  // open the shared library
  void* handle = dlopen(name, RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_LAZY);

  // extract the functions
  auto fun_pluggin_name = reinterpret_cast<pluggin_name_signature>(dlsym(handle, "pluggin_name"));
  auto fun_foo = reinterpret_cast<foo_signature>(dlsym(handle, "foo"));
  auto fun_bar = reinterpret_cast<bar_signature>(dlsym(handle, "bar"));

  // call them
  std::cout << "Calling Pluggin: " << fun_pluggin_name() << std::endl;
  fun_foo(2);
  fun_bar(3);

  // close the shared library
  dlclose(handle);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  for(int k = 1; k < argc; ++k) {
    execute_pluggin(argv[k]);
  }
}
```

Compile and link with the `dl` library:

```
$ g++ -o main main.cpp -std=c++14 -ldl
```

and run (notice you need the `./` before the name; this has to do with library naming conventions and search paths):

```
$ ./main ./pluggin_1.so ./pluggin_2.so
Calling Pluggin: Pluggin 1
2 * x = 4
 3 * y = 9
Calling Pluggin: Pluggin 2
20 * x = 40
 30 * y = 90
```

There are so many details that I left out (most importantly error management). I recommend you read the book [*API Design for C++*](http://www.apibook.com/blog/) to find alternative ideas (such as using an scripting language, using inheritance, using templates, and a mix of them).

I like the shared library method because then I can use the pluggins in other applications (for example: I can use Python's `ctypes` library, or Matlab's `loadlibrary`). I can also write the pluggin in, say, Fortran, and then wrap it in an interface compatible with the API.

Finally: notice that this has absolutely nothing to do with QT (though QT may provide a platform-independent shared library loader; I don't know). This is just a common manner in which people provide hooks for customization.

Answer (score 0):

The Qt Documentation provides a 'How To' on creating plugins to extend a Qt based application using Qt's own mechanisms. See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/plugins-howto.html.

It talks about a *high-level* API and a *low-level* API. You are interested in the *low-level* API.